# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child in React component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting this error in one of my components and I'm not able to figured out why.  I understand that a lot of people have had this issue when they return a reference to a function instead of actually calling it, but as far as I can tell, that isn't my issue.

EDIT: I have tried two things for testing purposes: replacing the entire return of the GameTable function with just an empty  tag, which produced the same error, and deleting the `cleanup()` function in `useEffect()` and it also produced the same error.

I also tried removing the `<GameTable/>` from Home/index.js and that did remove the error, so I know it's happening in that file.

Stacktrace:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in Unknown (at Home/index.js:37)
    in div (at Home/index.js:31)
    in HomePage (at withAuthorization.js:29)
    in WithAuthorization (at context.js:7)
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter() (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at ResponsiveDrawer/index.js:159)
    in main (at ResponsiveDrawer/index.js:152)
    in div (at ResponsiveDrawer/index.js:100)
    in ResponsiveDrawer (at App/index.js:21)
    in div (at App/index.js:20)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App/index.js:19)
    in App (at withAuthentication.js:32)
    in WithAuthentication (at context.js:7)
    in Unknown (at src/index.js:23)
    in ThemeProvider (at src/index.js:22)
```

Here is the file the error is coming from (GameTable/index.js):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { withFirebase } from "../Firebase";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";
import withAuthorization from "../Session/withAuthorization";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";

function GameTable(props) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [games, setGames] = useState([]);

    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        table: {
            minWidth: 640,
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
       setLoading(true);

        props.firebase.games(props.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', snapshot => {
            const gamesObject = snapshot.val();

            const gamesList = [];
            Object.keys(gamesObject).forEach((key) => {
                gamesList.push({[key]: gamesObject[key]})
            });

            setGames(gamesList);
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return function cleanup() {
            props.firebase.games().off();
        }
    });

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table}>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Opponent</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Goals</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Assists</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Points</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {games.map(game => (
                        <TableRow key={game.date}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {game.date}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{game.opponent}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{game.goals}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{game.assists}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{game.points}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}

GameTable.propTypes = {
        classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withAuthorization(withFirebase(GameTable));
```

and here is how it's being called in Home/index.js:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.fab}>
                <AddIcon />
            </Fab>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <p>The Home Page is accessible by every signed in user.</p>
            <GameTable/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  I import useEffect at the top, and then define it as one of the first things in the GameTable function

Comment: Yes, I noticed this after you added the import statements, my apologies

Comment: I highly doubt this, but could you try returning an arrow function in the function passed to `useEffect`?

Comment: I changed it to ```return () => {
            props.firebase.games().off();
        }``` and that didn't change the error

Comment: can you make sure the `games` in your state is an array of objects?

Comment: I'm not able to check that directly because that component isn't executing any code since it's giving the error, but games is initialized as an empty array and I'm pushing objects to it, so as far as I can tell, it should be an array of objects, yes

Comment: useState usage should simply be:

setLoading(true) and
setGames([])

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it, but it does not fix the error

Comment: Can you update your question to include a copy of the error object and stack trace? It may also be beneficial to include a running codesandbox with a minimal/reproducible demo that repros your issue.

Comment: I have added the stack trace to the question.  I don't know that I'll be able to do a sandbox, but the code is available on github if you'd like to view the full code https://github.com/jollygreenegiant/hockeystats

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved this.  By changing the export at the end to `export default withAuthorization(withFirebase(GameTable()));` (notice the added `()` after GameTable), I get a different error that gave me a specific line number inside of GameTable, which means the code inside the file is actually executing, which wasn't the case before.  The new error is unrelated I think, so the change in the export will, I believe, solve this issue.